# How to find out a default behavior/value for an Android API?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am learning Android programming, this seems to be a silly question.

```
pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
pd.setCancelable(false);
```

Cancelable can be

1. true
2. false
3. default behavior / not set

Is there an **easy way** to know the default behavior is either true or false?

In android Studio editor, use `ctrl + Q`, got this:[image]

Online reference does not help either. [setCancelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCancelable(boolean))

I can run the code, then know the result, but it gotta be a easy way, right?

Comment: Can't you control + click on the class that interests you and see on the library's source whether the `boolean flag` is set upon initialization on the class?

Comment: @George D, great! the easiest way. want to write it as an answer?

Comment: Posted my reply below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `control + click` (on Android Studio or Eclipse) on the class that interests you and see on the library's source whether the boolean flag is set upon initialization on the class.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look into its parent class: Dialog.
You can find out this line

```
 /**
 * This field should be made private, so it is hidden from the SDK.
 * {@hide}
 */
protected boolean mCancelable = true;
```

By the way ProgressDialog it's not recommend by Google. You should use ProgressBar instead. You have to handle block button or something like this while ProgressBar is showing, but it bring user a better UX

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the information would be on the online reference. However, as you point out, it isn't!

Whenever I find I need to know something like that, and it isn't documented, then [I check the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/4.4_r1-robolectric-0/android/app/Dialog.java#Dialog.0mCancelable). It is usually quite trivial to [search for the specific class source in Google](https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20source%20code%20dialog%20cancelable).

This of course, is only showing the value it takes by default for Android 4.4. In this case though, the value is unlikely to have a changed default. You should always bear that possibility in mind.